# Can't change configuration value at runtime, change doesn't save. Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

SettingController:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('backend.settings.index');
}

public function update(Request $request)
{
    $settings = $request->input('name');
    config(['settings.site_name' => $settings]);

    return redirect()->route('settings');
}
```

view:

```
<form action="{{ route('settings.update') }}" method="POST">
@csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Site name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ config('settings.site_name') }}" id="name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="paper-btn btn-secondary" value="Update">
    </div>
</form>
```

Variable $settings gets the correct data from input, I checked that with `dd()`, but change doesn't save after redirect. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... it isn't going to persist between requests because every request is a new PHP process booting the framework fresh, which will cause it to load the config from file (the config is just held in memory at run time) ... if you want to persist something you would have to write to the file or pull from some persistent storage and then set that value dynamically in a provider (run time) so it gets set every single time the framework boots

Comment: Have you tried Config::set('settings.site_name', $settings); to save the setting?

Comment: @MhluziBhaka that is what `config(['settings.site_name' => $settings]);` is doing, setting a config value, there is no 'saving' involved

Comment: Ah, thanks @lagbox. Thought that it might have some overriding function!

Comment: @lagbox Maybe it's better to use database for that. Then will be problem with passing variables from db to whole project..

Comment: yes the database and cache is most likely the way to go since this is dynamic apparently ... and there is no issue with getting this information ... as you already know you can set configuration values at run time so you can get those values and set them at run time

Comment: if you want an idea of how to handle settings outside the config system, i wrote this lil thing years ago: https://github.com/lagbox/settings .. `src/Settings.php` is a settings repository that uses the database to store the settings and can read settings from a config as well, and it caches the settings

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thank you, @lagbox.

Comment: @lagbox if you want, you can arrange this information as answer (because is it), and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your run time configuration settings like that won't persist as that Config Repository is only loading the config into memory and doesn't deal with persistence, so you are only setting an element in memory when you set a config value. That memory is gone after the request is finished; every request is starting a new process that is booting the framework fresh and loading the configuration.

You should probably look into storing your settings in the database and caching them. Then you could retrieve them from your persistent storage and then set those configuration values based on what you pulled for your settings (at run time).